# fatal error by updating a table via ajax

Tags: php, mysql

What is wrong here

**js**

```
function cstatus(status, user, pass){
    var id = $('.pmarked').data('id');
    console.log(id); // 101
    $.ajax({
        url: 'pro-status.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'status': status, 'user': user, 'pass': pass, 'id': id},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**pro-status.php**

```
$sql = "update posts set status = :astatus, user = :auser, pass = :apass, where id = :aid";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
    ":astatus" => $_POST['status'],
    ":auser" => $_POST['user'],
    ":apass" => $_POST['pass'],
    ":aid" => $_POST['id'] // line 12
));
```

**error**

> Fatal error... right syntax to use near 'where id = '101'' ... pro-status.php:12

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Can you give a better explanation of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Voting to close as **off-topic** due to a simple typo - there's a trailing comma `,` just before your `WHERE`.

Comment: solved, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the comma here:

```
pass = :apass, where id = :aid"
```

Should be:

```
pass = :apass where id = :aid"
```

In addition you should **never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
$sql = "update posts set status = :astatus, user = :auser, pass = :apass where id = :aid";
```

Just remove the `comma (,)` after the `:apass`

Comment: @bonaca Please check the code carefully before posting here. This kind of typo issues are common but it is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

Issue in SQL syntax please remove the comma and use this on $sql place.

```
$sql = "update posts set status = :astatus, user = :auser, pass = :apass where id = :aid";
```

Answer (score 2):

remove `,` before `where`

```
$sql = "update posts set status = :astatus, user = :auser, pass = :apass where id = :aid";
```